# what is the argument we get in callback of UIcontrol push button in Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I am showing lot of buttons on image using pushbutton with UIcontrol.(around 20)
How to handle callback with single function(which has similar behaviour and i just have to change id for each button,i dont want to write 20 callback for each.)

```
S = uicontrol('style','push',...
                     'units','pix',...
                     'position',Pos,...
                     'string',Button_name,...
                     'fontsize',10,...
                     'fontweight','bold');                      
                 set(S,'callback',{@pb1_call}) % Set the callbacks.
end
     function [] = pb1_call(varargin)
     disp(varargin)

 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Matlab documentation describes this reasonably well, look at uicontrol properties.

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject,eventdata)
display Goodbye
close(gcbf)
```

The callback fires with the firing object and event data. If you set a Tag onto the uicontrol you could do:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject,eventdata)
buttonID = get(hObject, 'Tag');
switch buttonID
    case 'button1'
    ...
end
```

Also worth noting, if the callback is a method of a handle class then there are three arguments:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(self, hObject, eventdata)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the callback function to an anonymous function, which will allow you to pass additional information to the callback

```
set(S,'callback',{@(u,v)pb1_call(u,v,buttonID}) % Set the callbacks.
```

Then your callback function will have the signature

```
function pb1_call(hObject,eventdata,buttonID)
```